# Python syntax error while trying to use sklearn.preprocessing

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been going through sentdex's python practical machine learning tutorial https://pythonprogramming.net/training-testing-machine-learning-tutorial/. Im trying to run the same code, with model_selection instead of cross validation but i get a syntax error when i get to preprocessing.scale(). 
This is my code:

```
import quandl

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import math

from sklearn import preprocessing, svm, model_selection

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open', 'Adj. High', 'Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]

df['HL_PT'] =  (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100
df['PT_Change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PT', 'PT_Change', 'Adj. Volume']]

forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))
print(forecast_out)

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['Label'] ,1)) 

y = np.array(df.drop(['Label'])
X = preprocessing.scale(X)

y2 = np.array(df['label'])

print(forecast_out)
```

This is the error message:

> runfile('D:/Course Materials/Data Science/mlpractice.py',
>   wdir='D:/Course Materials/Data Science') Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>
> File
>   "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2963, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('D:/Course Materials/Data Science/mlpractice.py', wdir='D:/Course Materials/Data Science')
>
> File
>   "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 786, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "G:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "D:/Course Materials/Data Science/mlpractice.py", line 36
>       X = preprocessing.scale(X)
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Cant progress any further without figuring out why this is happening. 
Any help would be really aprreciated!

Comment: missing trailing closing brace: `y = np.array(df.drop(['Label'])<--- here` should be `y = np.array(df.drop(['Label']))` vote to close as typo. Tip: when you get a syntax error and it looks baffling, check the line preceding it

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing bracket on this line:

```
y = np.array(df.drop(['Label'])
```

The line just before the one stated on the error message is usually where a syntax error is.